# не доходят email сообщения

Tags: php, email, хостинг

Шлю сообщение через функцию mail ,обработчик пишет,что все ок -сообщение отправлено,но сообщение не приходит на email.Может нужно как-то на хостинге почтовый ящик  настроить,я в этом пока новичок просто.

```
$adminEmail = 'moy@mail';
$hoEmail = 'otkogo@mail';
$message = 'message';
$subject = 'Новый заказ!';
self::send_mail($hoEmail,$adminEmail, $subject, $message);
```

вот send_mail :

```
public static function send_mail($from,$to,$subject,$body)
    {
        $charset = 'utf-8';
        mb_language("ru");
        $headers="MIME-VERSION: 1.0 \n";
        $headers .= "From: <".$from."> \n";
        $headers .= "Reply-To: <".$from. "> \n";
        $headers .= "Content-Type :text/html; charset =$charset \n";

        $subject = '=?'.$charset. '?B?' .base64_encode($subject). '?=';

        mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers);
    }
```

Comment: Письма могут отправляться в спам! Проверь письмо в спаме

Comment: Желательно привести код отправки писем.

Comment: нет,в спаме тоже нету

Comment: @Tofiq Şamedov, Что говорят логи? И, что за хостинг?

Comment: 99% что отправка писем на хостинге заблокирована

Comment: Скорей всего нужно настроить SMTP. Посмотрите логи  почтового сервера, любой адекватный хостинг дает к ним доступ